# Cannot determine current directory

Tags: java, jvm

I am trying to run a .jar file that was created successfully in Netbeans and I am receiving the following error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM java.lang.Error: 
>   Properties init: Could not determine current working directory. at 
>   java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method) at 
>   java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1070)

The command that I type to run the .jar is

```
java -jar "/path to the dist forlder/EOPPrototype.jar"
```

My classpath is as follows:

```
CLASSPATH=/opt/netbeans-7.1.2/ide/modules/ext/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-     bin.jar:/h/USERS/local/pagola/NetBeansProjects/mylib/dist/mylib.jar:/h/USERS/local/pagola/NetBeansProjects/EOPPrototype/build/classes:.
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 217):

I saw the same error when I was trying to call `java -version` inside a directory, which I already had deleted from another terminal session. Of course in that case java `could not determine the current working directory`, simply because it didn't exist.

Comment: this happened to me when i issued a command in the maven target directory that: was present, then i did a clean and build (clean install), then issued the same command. Even though the path was still valid, the specific directory entry i issued the command in first was not there (OS X) doing a cd ../target fixed my issue

Comment: ..aaand how does one fix this?

Comment: I had the same problem calling `java -v` from `/Applications/NetBeans-8.1beta/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated`. That 'generated' folder is a regenerated cache folder from NetBeans. When I cd-ed out then back to the same /generated the problem did not happen and java -version worked giving `java version "1.8.0_60"`

Comment: Simply get out and enter again in the directory

Comment: In my case, I touched a file in dist folder and was trying to read it from there after doing a clean+build project. Moved the file out of dist folder and no more complaints.

Comment: What a weird issue. Happened to me tonight and this was exactly what it was. I was inside `<project>/target/classes` in a terminal, ran a `mvn clean compile`, and then tried re-running the java command from the first terminal. I guess the Maven command deleting and re-creating the directory screwed the old terminal up. Using `cd` to go back to the project root and then back into the `classes` directory fixed it for me.

Answer (score 38):

Solution: cd to another directory and run that command again, that works for me.

See explanation here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8186434

Comment: It happens when a folder you're in was removed

Answer (score 13):

In Fedora 21, I tried calling the "java -version" after an uninstall and it gave the above error. Close all the terminals and open them again and try.

Should work.

Comment: Same for me, with ubuntu

Comment: Same for me also, with LinuxMint 18.3.

Comment: Same for me with Debian in WSL

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error message, but I'm not sure if it was for the same reason as I don't use Netbeans. I use my terminal and compile with `ant`.

I `cd`'d to a directory to run a `javafile.class` file. The file I want to run is part of a bigger package. The directory structure of the package looked something like this: `a/b/c/javafile.class`. The `a`, `b`, and `c` directories are all part of a larger package.

To run my `javafile.class`, I `cd`'d into `a` and ran the file from there: `java b/c/javafile`. After I made some changes and recompiled with my `ant` script, the directory I was in had been deleted and remade by `ant`. So, when I ran `javafile.class` again, I got the error you're getting.

I fixed my problem by `cd`ing out of the directories that are deleted and remade by `ant` and then running my `javafile.class` again.

Comment: Thanks. Navigating out of a high-up directory and down to a lower one, then re-running my command fixed the issue for me too.

Answer (score 4):

maybe you did not config java environment on your workstation correctly

the following configurations were what I did in my mac

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

and add those in it

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH:.
CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:.
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
export CLASSPATH
```

replace

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
```

with your jdk version
and then run

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

to use these config immediately 
then you can check by

```
java -version
```

Comment: Cool. Great Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error -

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.

by just doing 'java -version' (you would think it wouldn't need to bring up a
virtual machine just to answer a simple question like 'what version are you?')

A higher up element (that between the slashes) of the directory path of the pwd
had spaces in it.  When I made the current working directory one which from /
downward didn't have any spaces the 'java -version' command got a proper response.

I'm concluding they didn't account for directories with spaces when they
programmed it.  But that was version 1.7.  I've now loaded version 8 so hopefully
it has been corrected.

Comment: I had the same problem calling `java -v` from `/Applications/NetBeans-8.1beta/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated` (has dots and hyphens, not spaces, but they might also cause problems [NO, see EDIT]). Then I got OK `java version "1.8.0_60"` (seems is still a problem with Java8. EDIT: it was because that 'generated' folder is a regenerated cache folder from NetBeans. When I cd-ed out then back to the same /generated it did not happen. asmaier (below) is right.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error on Mac OS X and this is a genuine error since the directory has vanished. The directory I was when I am executing the commands is `<PROJECT DIR>\target`.

> The problem was I opened two terminals in the other terminal I ran `mvn clean install` and the target directory from `PROJECT DIR` got deleted and recreated.

My old terminal from where I was executing Java commands is not in a valid directory.

> The file descriptor is invalid since the directory got deleted by Maven.

When I moved back to the parent directory and the changed back to the `target` directory, the `java` command started working correctly as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Under CentOS, rhel, SL or SLC? Not an issue under debian/ubuntu.

I found you need to logout of the shell you are using and log back in. The environment is not set up initially correctly for the current shell. After login I see that:  java -version will work.

Also ensure that /etc/alternatives/java actually points to something reasonable like:

```
ls -lisa /etc/alternatives/java
72645 0 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 46 May 27 11:29 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
```

Answer (score 0):

Just now, i got the same error. because i use java to setreuid/setregid to apache:apache, when i change back to root:root, i changed gid before uid, the real result is root:apache. everything going wrong, such as the error say "java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory. "

you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this error in my mac, when I start tomcat from my eclipse. After setting JAVA_HOME and restarting the eclipse, the error is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install default-jdk first !
sudo apt install default-jdk
only version 11 does not set all the environment correctly
in place of : sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk

Answer (score -1):

You may get this error if you issue "java -version" or other java command from a read-only directory. For example using openjdk 8 on centos (as non-root user):

```
cd /usr/bin
java -version
```

Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.