# Eclipse won't open in Linux Mint and Java won't open in different directories

Tags: linux, eclipse, java

I had Installed Eclipse in `/opt/eclipse` in Linux Mint 18.2 cinnamon with openjdk-9 (please don't tell me switch over oracle jdk). Whenever I click on Eclipse icon this window shows up:

[image: windows]

Here is the content of that window:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.7.1.20171005-1200/splash.bmp
-launcher /opt/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.550.v20170928-1359/eclipse_1629.so
-startup /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 828016
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
```

Here is my Java:

```
$java -version
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

Also when I type the same command in `/opt/eclipse` I get this:

```
/opt/eclipse $ java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.
    at java.lang.System.initProperties(java.base/Native Method)
    at java.lang.System.initPhase1(java.base/System.java:1850)
```

when I try to open it from terminal I get this:-

```
$ eclipse 
Unrecognized option: --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

Comment: I suppose if `java -version` would work, Eclipse would also work. Does the `/opt/eclipse` directory exist and is it a real directory (not only a link)? https://stackoverflow.com/q/11038056/6505250

Comment: @howlger thanks sir,/opt/eclipse is real.I have added some information at the bottom.Please take a look at it.

Comment: Eclipse oxygen is recommended for java 9. You seem to have neon. Not sure about that constellation.

Comment: @JoopEggen it's oxygen

Comment: Remove the line `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM` in the file `eclipse.ini` and try again.

Comment: @howlger Thanks that worked !!! Can You tell what does it really did ??

Comment: I ran into this as well... apparently, the `openjdk-9-jdk` package in the Xenial repo is not Java 9, but something older. `java -version` said something like "9-internal" (huh?), so I guess the Eclipse installer concludes that this is Java 9. But it's something older, as it misses methods that were added in Java 9... So, Java 9+ just need to be installed from somewhere else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In** the file **`eclipse.ini` remove the line `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM`**.

In Java 9 the [Java Platform Module System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) was introduced which encapsulate most internal APIs. The `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM` is a Java 9 virtual machine (VM) argument to make it behave like before Java 9.

See *[JEP 261: Module System](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#ALL-SYSTEM)*:

> As a further special case at run time, if  is `ALL-SYSTEM` then
>   all system modules are added to the root set, whether or not they are
>   in the default set. This is sometimes needed by test harnesses. This
>   option will cause many modules to be resolved; in general, `ALL-DEFAULT`
>   should be preferred.

Comment: Came here for a similar problem when launching an "Eclipse application" (e.g. for plugin development) in Eclipse Oxygen in JDK 8. For some reason, in "Project Properties" > "Run/Debug Setiings" > "Eclipse Application" > "Arguments" > "VM Arguments" contains `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM`. Remove it there.