# Error when installing Eclipse on Linux Mint

Tags: eclipse

I just followed the Eclipse websites links to download the latest version for Debian, and after running from the terminal

```
$ ./eclipse-inst
```

It goes through the installation process but returns

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-Duser.dir=/root/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse
-jar /root/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /root/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /root/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.700.v20180518-1200/eclipse_1705.so
-startup /root/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata eb0026
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-Duser.dir=/root/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse
-jar /root/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
```

I wasn't able to search the error but it may be because the error is so massive that I don't know which parts of it to search for.  I tried searching the initial segment of the error and didn't find much that was useful.  What I did find indicated editing the `eclipse.ini` file, so I did that, and it now looks like the following: [Edit: after the advice of a proposed answer I updated the file to look like the following]

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
#--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
#256m
--launcher.appendVmargs

-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-DEFAULT
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
```

However, after making this edit I see no difference in the error message that the installer brings up.

I believe it's also possible to get Eclipse not by downloading the installer but by using a repo--but as I understand it, this repo usually has a slightly outdated version of Eclipse.  I could certainly be wrong, but I believe I've seen advice that it's best to download and use the installer.

When I run `java -version` it returns

```
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

When I try to run Eclipse it pops up an error message

```
An error has occurred. See the log file
/home/bob/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1533437446117.log.
```

And interestingly, the folder in which the file is supposed to exist, doesn't exist.

Comment: If that build ID is correct and based on dates, 2016-04-14 would be a prerelease build of Java 9, from more than a year and a half before release. Don't trust it. Also, if `-vm` is in your eclipse.ini, it should be on a line by itself, followed by a line pointing to the JVM binary, also by itself.

Comment: Hm, so I need to update my Java version?  Shouldn't it do this automatically when I run `sudo apt update`?  I'll edit the `eclipse.ini` file as it is now--I also found this link suggesting the `ALL-SYSTEM` thing is incorrect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807468/eclipse-wont-open-in-linux-mint-and-java-wont-open-in-different-directories

Comment: @nitind Interestingly, although I have edited `ALL-SYSTEM` to be `ALL-DEFAULT` when I now try to run the installer the error message still contains `Unrecognized option: --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM`.  However when I run eclipse the error message now says `Unrecognized option: --add-modules=ALL-DEFAULT`.

Comment: I feel like maybe I'm editing the wrong `ini` file or something.  I'm editing the one in `/usr/lib/eclipse/` but if there's another one I'm not sure how to find out about it.

Comment: I don't know about Mint, or what versions of openjdk it has in its repositories. I just know that a build that old might not understand the same arguments as the release version, and the unrecognized option *is* known to release versions of Java 9.

Comment: @nitind If you want to submit that as an answer I'll accept it--I just found that Java 9 is EOL and that's why the given update is the most recent.  Since Java 10 isn't yet available in openJDK I reverted to Java 8 and this solved all of my problems.

Comment: https://adoptopenjdk.net/ has 9 and 10 builds for most platforms, if you should still want to work with those versions for your own projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a prerelease build of Java 9, and as such might not support the command line arguments expected in the actual release. Java 9 is current until the end of September, so try the released version if you can.

Answer (score 0):

you have to adjust the `eclipse.ini` in order to [configure Eclipse for Java 9](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9) ...for example:

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

or use Java 8 ...

[I just installed Eclipse on Linux, but it does not start. What is the problem?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/IRC_FAQ#I_just_installed_Eclipse_on_Linux.2C_but_it_does_not_start._What_is_the_problem.3F)

> Quite often, Eclipse will not work properly with non-Sun or non-IBM JVMs. These issues are usually related to Blackdown or GCJ. Eclipse has a list of reference platforms that it is tested against which you should try to match against. Try installing one from Sun, IBM, or BEA (eg., Sun JDK 5.0, IBM JDK 5.0, or BEA JRockit 5.0). Version 6 of OpenJDK works too, particularly with Fedora Eclipse.

Comment: Should your example be the whole `eclipse.ini` file?  Or is this suppose to replace some part of it?

Comment: I made my best guess about what the edited `eclipse.ini` file should look like and the error doesn't change.

Comment: @Addem maybe try Oracle Java 8? `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Comment: Well when I try that it times out, and the terminal keeps printing `Aug 05, 2018 2:07:57 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://www.eclipse.org:80` over and over.  But I just noticed something else weird: It's trying to install this to folder `/root/eclipse/` and the folder doesn't even exist.

Comment: Hm, correction, now I find it after I make myself root ... not sure what that's about, but anyway.

Comment: Interesting, when I try to run Eclipse as root part of the error reads `Unrecognized option: --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM`.  The link you sent had a lot about Windows in it, are you sure this isn't the command in Windows?

Comment: Never mind about Windows, looking back over the link it doesn't mention that, sorry.